# Preponderance of Greek authorship in digital signal processing?

Tags: discussion

If ever there were a 'meta' question...am I just engaging in confirmation bias because it would be strange if this were true or is there an anomalous interest in Greek university faculty in signal processing? I'm encountering a lot Greek names in signal processing, in American faculties but also abroad. Is there some historical reason for this, or proximity to the ocean? Perhaps because I live in a Greek neighborhood in New York City and notice these names more easily?

Comment: :-) I resemble that remark. :-)  Yes, it is quite amusing. I've noticed the same thing: very many Greek or Greek-derived names in the field, compared with other fields in EE.

Comment: I even remember a more narrow anecdote on the interest of Greek origin fellows in nonlinear signal processing. When ask why, the Greek scholar said: because linear is too easy